# Get systemd dependencies from configuration files

Tags: systemd

Is there some tool that can create a graph of unit dependencies statically from systemd configuration files?

`systemd-analyze dot` AFAIU does it at run-time, but I have a special directory (not in /etc/systemd or wherever the systemd keeps the config files after installation) with all the *.service files and want to know which unit starts before which from those files.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you are concerned about actually running the tasks first, you could 
 Replace their "ExecStart=" lines with something safe like "/bin/echo 'Hello World'". Then start them in your current systemd.

From there, you can use tools like `systemd-analyze dot` to visualize the dependencies.